# How to use OR and AND operators in RPN (Reverse Polish Notation)?

Tags: rpn

How do I use OR and AND operators in RPN (Reverse Polish Notation) ?

I have something like this:

```
"type" valueOf "XY" ==
```

this means if the type is XY then something happens. Now I want to add another option to "XY", lets say "AB". From what I know it should look something like this

```
"type" valueOf "XY" "AB" || ==
```

but of course it isn't. Where is my problem?

Answer (score 3):

What you've written amounts to

```
valueOf("type") == "XY" || "AB"
```

which does not express what I suspect you mean in any notation. What you meant was probably

```
valueOf("type") == "XY" || valueOf("type") == "AB"
```

so try to translate that to RPN.

Comment: So `"type" valueOf "XY" == "type" valueOf "AB" == ||`

Comment: this:
"type" valueOf "XY" == 
is a fix and working term. I tried tripleee 's solution but it is not working